# Configuring value for numberReturned for WFS

Tags: geoserver, wfs, configuration

The query

```
GEOSERVER/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&StoredQuery_ID=all&outputFormat=JSON
```

gives me the following answer

```
type    "FeatureCollection"
features    
0   {…}
1   {…}
2   {…}
3   {…}
4   {…}
totalFeatures   21350
numberMatched   21350
numberReturned  5
timeStamp   "2019-12-14T12:03:06.475Z"
crs 
type    "name"
properties  
name    "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833"
```

The relevant part is

```
totalFeatures   21350
numberMatched   21350
numberReturned  5
```

My StoredQuery looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:StoredQueryDescription xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="all">
    <wfs:QueryExpressionText isPrivate="false" language="urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression" returnFeatureTypes="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f">
        <wfs:Query wfs:typeNames="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f">

         <fes:Filter>
          <fes:Within>
            <fes:ValueReference>shape</fes:ValueReference>
                        <gml:Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833">
                            <gml:lowerCorner>353038.3125 5840211.5</gml:lowerCorner>
                            <gml:upperCorner>378832.09375 5858933.5</gml:upperCorner>
                        </gml:Envelope>
          </fes:Within>
        </fes:Filter>

        </wfs:Query>
    </wfs:QueryExpressionText>
</wfs:StoredQueryDescription>
```

I would like to have all 21350 features returned and not only 5. Where can I change the setting for valueReturned value?

What have I tried so far?

1.
I added `count=100` to the query.

```
GEOSERVER/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&StoredQuery_ID=all&outputFormat=JSON&count=100
```

`count=100` is ignored by GeoServer. I see the same result but no error.

2.
I tried `GEOSERVER/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&outputFormat=JSON&typeNames=sg_flurstueck_f` which led to the same result.

[image]
This is the information on the GeoServer that should show me 50 features?

Where can I configure the value for `numberReturned`?

Comment: Have you verified how many features there are within you area `<gml:lowerCorner>353038.3125 5840211.5</gml:lowerCorner>
                            <gml:upperCorner>378832.09375 5858933.5</gml:upperCorner>`?

Comment: You can't set the numberReturned. It describes the data. If you ask service to return nine features `https://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typenames=states&count=9&format=application/json` the numberReturned is 9.